# Why I can't make background color on id footer

Tags: html, css

I want to copy Google homepage and I want to fill the background color on `div` id footer. But it doesn't work.

This is my code:

http://codepen.io/jakzaizzat/pen/cqnIJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `<ul class="first">` and `<ul class="second">`

Is in float left and right,

It would be best if you put `<div class="clear"></div>`

which `.clear { clear:both; }`

In the footer.

It would be like this

```
   <div id="footer">
     <ul class="first">
       <li><a href="#">Advertising</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="second">
        <li><a href="#">Privacy & Terms</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Use Google.com</a></li>
      </ul>
     <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>
```

Or make the `ul` inside the footer display inline block with their corresponding width.

And other solution that I'm doing when I'm using floats.

It uses the auto clear method. Yaaay!

```
.auto-clear:before, .auto-clear:after { content:" "; display:table; }
.auto-clear:after { clear:both; }
```

Put `auto-clear` class on the parent of the floats.

So it would be like `<div id="footer" class="auto-clear">` you may remove the `<div class="clear"></div>`

So it would be like this

```
<div id="footer" class="auto-clear">
<-- content here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#footer {
  background-color:#e7e7e7;
  overflow:auto
}
```

try this. by just adding "overflow:auto" to #footer, the background color appears. when you have floating divs in a container div, you usually have to handle the overflow property of the container div.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any background color because both of your nested div's have `float:left` once you use float on a element it loses it's height.

So essentially you have a wrap that is 0px high and no color is visible to you. You can fix this by adding another DIV after your second float div with a `clear:fix` this will clear all your nested elements and your `background-color:` will show.

I hope this helps you and you learn something new :) ... Good luck with your project!

Also @Asbar answer works as well. I have upvoted his answer!

Answer (score 0):

EDITED

Well Answered by Wesley Lachenal

Comment: a fixed height on the footer isn't the answer. Clearing the floated elements is.